# ¿Cómo en un ciclo for detener la ejecución de una consulta snmp por terminal y continuar con dicho ciclo en PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, linux, bash, bucles

Mucho gusto primeramente, quisiera que alguien amablemente me pudiera ayudar con una duda que cargo y no he podido resolver en PHP y que involucra consultas SNMP. Cabe destacar ante todo, que realmente hay cosas que no sé de este lenguaje, porque es mi primera vez programando "full" de lleno en este lenguaje y en el codigo que les muestre si lo ven muy extenso o errores de algun tipo, me disculpan y estoy totalmente abierta a cualquier sugerencia! :)

Ahora bien, el contexto del programa que estoy realizando para mi empresa que trabajo, es que el script en PHP debe encontrar de X dispositivo (El "parent") que se desee, a través de consultas por SNMP lograr saber cuáles son sus "childs" para más adelante graficarlo en Nagios Core. Todo esto de manera automatica (por asi decirlo).

Tengo que destacar antes de explicar en si la problematica con ello, que: no posee una base de datos de SQL o algo por el estilo, sino que la informacion se guarda en distintos archivos de texto (dependiendo del tipo de informacion obtenida); Utilizo ajuro SNMP porque es lo que me ha pedido la empresa y no me permiten utilizar otro medio ya que no poseo ciertos permisos para experimentar con otra cosa, por lo que estoy un poco limitada con mis opciones; y he elegido PHP porque es el lenguaje que domino un poco mas, aunque pude usar algun otro (como Perl, Bash, ect.) de verdad por tiempo y mis pasantias e inexperiencia, preferí este lenguaje... Pero si es posible en la solución agregar otro lenguaje como Javascript, Bash o algo por el estilo es bienvenida la idea!.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Ahora si, en una parte del código cuando se ejecuta por primera vez, crea una especie de base de datos conformado por distintos archivos de texto con una informacion en especifica. La base de datos en si se conforma por:

- /DB_checkmap/nagios_db  <--- Donde almacena unos 2 archivos de texto con los nombres e ip's de dispositivos que hay en la base de datos de Nagios Core (list_names.txt y list_hosts.txt)
- /DB_checkmap/nagios_db/database_MAC  <--- Donde se almacenan los archivos de texto con el listado de MACs y Puertos recabado por SNMP de los dispositivos registrados en Nagios

El extracto del codigo utilizado para crear los archivos en database_MAC es el siguiente:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php



///// DIRECCIONES /////////////////////////////

$dir_actual = trim(shell_exec('pwd'));
$dir_nagios = '/usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts/';
$dir_bdcheck = "/DB_checkmap";
$dir_bddevices = "/DB_checkmap/devices_db";
$dir_bdnagios = "/DB_checkmap/nagios_db";
$dir_name = $dir_actual . $dir_bdnagios . '/list_name.txt';
$dir_hosts = $dir_actual . $dir_bdnagios . '/list_host.txt';
$dir_databaseMAC = $dir_actual . $dir_bdnagios . '/database_MAC';


//// OID'S USADAS/////////////////////////////////

$ifPhysAdd = '1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6';
$ARP = 'dot1dTpFdbTable';


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// LISTADO DE MACS (NAGIOS)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


$ip[] = array();
$ips[] = array();
$hosts_n[] = array();

foreach(file($dir_hosts) as $line) {
  $hosts_n[] = $line;
}

unset($hosts_n[0]);
unset($hosts_n[0]);

foreach($hosts_n as $element){
 $ip[] = explode(' ', $element);
}
unset($ip[0]);

$i7 = count($ip);

for($x=1; $x<=$i7; $x++) {
        $ips[] = $ip[$x][1];
}


///////////////////////

$nombre[] = array();
$nombres[] = array();
$nombres_n[] = array();

foreach(file($dir_name) as $line) {
  $nombres_n[] = $line;
}


$i7 = count($nombres_n);
unset($nombres_n[0]);

foreach($nombres_n as $element){
 $nombre[] = explode(' ', $element);
}
unset($nombre[0]);

$i8 = count($nombre);

for($x=1; $x<=$i8; $x++) {
        $nombres[] = $nombre[$x][1];
}


unset($nombres[0]);
unset($ips[0]);

foreach($nombres as $element){
$names[] = $element;    // Aqui he creado un arreglo con los nombres de los dispositivos que voy a aplicarles la consulta SNMP,
}                        // esto es mas para nombrar cada archivo con la infomación coon el nombre del dispositivo.

foreach($ips as $element){
$address[] = $element;   // Aqui la lista de sus IP de los dispositvos para aplicarles el SNMP 
}


///////////////////////////
//////////////////////////


$x2 = count($names) - 1;

for ($x=0; $x<=$x2; $x++){ // creo un ciclo donde, por cada dispositivo...

  $nombre_archivo = $dir_databaseMAC . '/' . trim($names[$x]) . '.txt';  // creo el nombre de su archivo de texto donde se guardara la info
$consulta_bd = 'snmpwalk -v2c -c \\' . $argv[1] . ' ' . trim($address[$x]) . ' ' . $ifPhysAdd; // creo su consulta snmp personalizada (el $argv[1] es la comunidad SNMP que coloque el usuario desde un principio)
  $mac_n = array();
  $macs_nagios = array();
  $macaddress_n = array();
  $macaddress = array();
  $resultado4 = "";

$resultado4 = shell_exec($consulta_bd . ' 2>&1'); // ejecuto la consulta SNMP


if(strncasecmp($resultado4, 'IF-MIB::ifPhysAddress.', 22) === 0){ //si el archivo posee este texto (como comienza el resultado SNMP correctamente)

$array4 = explode("\n", $resultado4); //empieza a manipular y guardar la informacion
$u = count($array4);
$u1 = $u - 1;


unset($array4[$u1]);

$u = count($array4) - 1;

for ($z=0; $z<=$u; $z++){
  $macs_nagios[] = explode(" ", $array4[$z]);
  unset($macs_nagios[$z][1]);
 if ($macs_nagios[$z][3] != NULL) {
        $mac_n[] = $macs_nagios[$z][3];
        $index_n[] = $macs_nagios[$z][0];
}
}


$u3 = count($mac_n) - 1;
  for ($y=0; $y<=$u3; $y++) {
  $n_array5[] = explode(".", $index_n[$y]);
  $macaddress_n[] = array($n_array5[$y][1], $mac_n[$y]);

}

foreach($macaddress_n as $info){
$texto2 = $info[0] . ' ' . $info[1] . "\n";
  file_put_contents($nombre_archivo, $texto2, FILE_APPEND); //aqui lo guarda en su archivo de texto
}

echo "archivo listo " . trim($names[$x]) . "\n"; //y muestra un mensaje de confirmacion 



}
else{echo "no lo detecta " . trim($names[$x]) . "\n";} //de otra manera, quiere decir que no lo detecta y siga probando con otra IP

}


?>
```

El problema radica en que al ejecutar la consulta SNMP, como se prueba con muchos dispositivos hay algunos que no tienen habilitado SNMP y solamente (por decir algo) un 40% de los dispositivos registrados en la base de datos si lo reconoce y genera la informacion (tarda como 1 milisegundo, es rapido), pero con esos dispositivos  (el 60% restante) que no tiene SNMP, cuando ejecuta la consulta tarda mucho en decir el mensaje de error que no tiene habilitado SNMP (en promedio como 7seg maximo con cada uno). El cual para mi es un problema grande ya que, con una gran cantidad de dispositivos a realizar esta comprobacion inicial, me ha tardado en recorrer tooodos los dispositivos hasta 3 horas solamente alli. Y necesito que no tarde demasiado pues. Hay alguna manera de solucionar esto?

Mis posibles ideas era que en PHP o algun otro lenguaje que se le pueda anexar, habra una funcion que me diga "si esta linea que se esta ejecutando se ha pasado de los 2 o 3 seg de ejecucion, deten el proceso y sigue el ciclo".

O alguna manera de que en el mismo SNMP se pueda reducir el tiempo de respuesta de error?

He investigado un poco pero las funciones en PHP y Javascript es más para procesos que ya finalizaron y le cronometraron su tiempo de ejecucion hasta su final, no los que se estan ejecutando al momento pues, que es lo que necesito.

De verdad les estaria muy agradecida si me ayudan con esto!!. Disculpen las molestias causadas y gracias por su tiempo!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como estás trabajando con una aplicación externa (snmpwalk).
Lo ideal sería poner un timeout ahí.
Hay dos parámetros que te pueden servir:

1. Con `-t` definis el timeout (podrías usar 1 segundo).
2. Con `-r` definis los retrys (re-intentos, con 1 debería ir bien en una red estable).

Quedaría así:
`snmpwalk -v2c -t 1 -r 1`

### Saltar iteración actual en PHP

Se hace de la siguiente manera usando `continue`:

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i) {
    if ($i == 2)
        continue
    print "$i\n";
}
```

> `continue` se utiliza dentro de las estructuras iterativas para saltar el resto de la iteración actual del bucle y continuar la ejecución en la evaluación de la condición, para luego comenzar la siguiente iteración.

[mas info sobre continue](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.continue.php)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! me ha servido n.n